# Create github teams in r without using PAT

Tags: r, github

I am working with GitHub through R and am trying to setup my team. When I input the following code (after already specifying my PAT (personal access token in the r environment):

```
library(gh)

gh("POST /orgs/organisation/teams",
+    name = new_team,
+    description = "desc", .token = "github_pat_tokenID")
```

I receive the following error:

```
Error in `gh()`:
! GitHub API error (403): Resource not accessible by personal access token
```

My understanding is that the security rules may have changed and PATs may no longer be usable for authentication. If this is the case, is there still a way to create teams for GitHub in R, or must this be done manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the API requires you to use your OAuth bearer token, not the PAT. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/teams/teams?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-team). Also, you should read the docs on [how to authenticate with the API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/authenticating-to-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28#basic-authentication).

Here is an example from the documentation with the parameters for your request.

```
curl -L \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/teams \
  -d '{"name":"Justice League","description":"A great team","permission":"push","notification_setting":"notifications_enabled","privacy":"closed"}'
```